# configure custom plugin using params from extension

Tags: gradle

Hi i'm trying to dynamically create and configure task based on plugin extension values, problem seems to be evaluation order, is there any way to work around it?

```
apply plugin: SetupPlugin 

setup {
     destDir = 'some directory set per project in build.gradle'
     sourceFile = 'some file set per project in build.gradle' 
}


class PluginExtension {
    String destDir
    String sourceFile
}

class SetupPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    def placeholders

    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create("setup", PluginExtension)

        project.task ("setupEnvironment", type: Copy) {
            doFirst() {
                //computes placeholders <-- project.setup has value here
            }

            into (project.setup.destDir){ //<-- project.setup is null
                from project.setup.sourceFile
            }
            filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: placeholders)
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving this into the doFirst block can cause some sideeffects, as the gradle up to date task might run into problems as reconfigure the parameters of your copy task at execution time instead of configuration time. A quickfix which should do the trick is to defer the evaluation by using closures:

```
...
void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create("setup", PluginExtension)

        project.task ("setupEnvironment", type: Copy) {
            doFirst() {
                //computes placeholders <-- project.setup has value here
            }

            into {project.setup.destDir}
            from { project.setup.sourceFile }
            filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: placeholders)
        }   
}
...
```

hope that helped!

cheers,
René

Answer (score 0):

It is because `apply` is called before applying setup settings.

It works for `doFirst` because it called after `apply` during build. 
Maybe you may wrap your copy into `doLast`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I asked a question that I think is very similar to this one. I may be missing a subtle difference, but in case it helps: [here it is.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218888/can-gradle-extensions-handle-lazy-evaluation-of-a-property)