# Can gradle extensions handle lazy evaluation of a property?

Tags: gradle

I'm writing a custom gradle plugin to handle some vaguely complicated work and I have run into a frustrating problem while using properties to configure some of the tasks that the plugin applies.

```java
apply plugin: myPlugin

//Provide properties for the applied plugin
myPluginProps {
    message = "Hello"
}

//Define a task that uses my custom task directly
task thisTaskWorksFine(type: MyTask) {
    input = myPluginProps.message
}

//Define a plugin that will apply a task of my custom type
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create('myPluginProps', MyPluginExtension)

        project.task(type: MyTask, 'thisTaskWorksIncorrectly') {
            input = project.myPluginProps.message
        }
    }
}

//The extension used by my custom plugin to get input
class MyPluginExtension {
    def String message
}

//The task used by both the standard build section and the plugin
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    def String input

    @TaskAction
    def action() {
        println "You gave me this: ${input}"
    }
}
```

The results from using this file are as follows:

```
$ gradle thisTaskWorksFine thisTaskWorksIncorrectly
:thisTaskWorksFine
You gave me this: Hello
:thisTaskWorksIncorrectly
You gave me this: null

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I consider this to be very unexpected. To my mind, applying a task from the plugin and writing one directly should result in the same output when given the same input. In this case, both tasks are given `myPluginProps.message` as input, but the task applied by the plugin is greedy and evaluates to null early on. (During the apply phase?)

The only solution I have found is to use closures in the plugin task's configuration block like so:

```java
//Define a plugin that will apply a task of my custom type
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create('myPluginProps', MyPluginExtension)

        project.task(type: MyTask, 'thisTaskWorksIncorrectly') {
            input = { project.myPluginProps.message }
        }
    }
}
```

That solves the greedy evaluation problem pretty nicely *except* that now the custom task has to be modified to expect and deal with a closure. It's not terrifically hard to do, but I don't think it should be the task's responsibility to deal with the closure, since the plugin is "to blame".

Am I using extensions incorrectly here? Or are they just not adequate? The official stance appears to be that [we should use extensions](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/whats_the_difference_between_plugin_conventions_vs_plugin_extensions) but I've yet to find any examples where extensions could do what I need. I can move forward with my use of closures and writing a bunch of boilerplate getters that do closure eval and setters that can handle closures and normal types, but it seems very against the philosophy of groovy and therefore gradle. I would be very happy if there is a way that I can use extensions and get the lazy evaluation automatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT**

The below answer is now outdated. Since I provided it a better mechanism than convention mappings has been introduced for doing this called [lazy properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#lazy_configuration).

---

The usual solution for this problem is to use convention mapping:

```groovy
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
       project.extensions.create('myPluginProps', MyPluginExtension)

        project.task(type: MyTask, 'thisTaskWorksIncorrectly') {
            conventionMapping.input = { project.myPluginProps.message }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the task:

```groovy
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    def String input

    @TaskAction
    def action() {
        println "You gave me this: ${getInput()}"
    }
```

}

Please note that I explicitly used getter for `input` - the convention mapping won't kick in if you reference the field directly.

Comment: Is there a difference between convention mapping and conventions? Your answer looks pretty slick, so I will almost certainly use it, but one of the core devs has said "In short, only use extensions, don't use conventions." Maybe I took that overly literally.

Comment: The [conventions](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:convention) that Peter is mentioning are the old mechanism for extensions. The difference is that you get the dsl (`myPluginProps { message = "Hello" }`) for free with extensions and you didn't get them with conventions. Conventions and convention mappings are two different things and convention mappings are used internally in [gradle code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L131) a lot.

Comment: Excellent. In my research I was dodging everything that mentioned the word convention, but that was hasty. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 13):

The answer by Peter in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379967/retrieving-conventionmapping-in-custom-plugin#comment39598034_25388282) indicates that conventionMapping feature will definitely go away. It's best to avoid it.

Using `afterEvaluate` to solve the *deferred configuration issue* has made my code a lot cleaner than the conventionMapping approach.

```groovy
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create('myPluginProps', MyPluginExtension)

        project.afterEvaluate {
            project.task(type: MyTask, 'thisTaskWorksIncorrectly') {
                input = project.myPluginProps.message
            }
        }
    }
}
```