# Retrieving conventionMapping in custom plugin

Tags: gradle

I'm writing a gradle custom plugin which uses my custom extension object. I got to understand that I have to use conventionMapping to lazily evaluate the extension object value from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16220879/2464295) and [gradle forum](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/writing_custom_plugin_which_uses_convention_plus_external_project_properties).

The problem happens when I'm trying to write my plugin with the normal Gradle API (not the **DSL API**). I figured that I wanted to do this because it is more IDE friendly. So the task creation is done like so:

```
MyTask task = project.tasks.create("mytask", MyTask)
task.?conventionMapping? ..
```

instead of

```
project.task(type:MyTask) {
   conventionMapping.field = ..
}
```

MyTask is extending DefaultTask, so it doesn't have conventionMapping field. Then I found out that some of the Task implementation from Gradle's Java plugin is extending ConventionTask, which I thought I should extend from, but unfortunately these facts make me confused again:

1. ConventionTask package is internal
2. DefaultTask is annotated with @NoConventionMapping

I also found [this thread](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/whats_the_difference_between_plugin_conventions_vs_plugin_extensions) saying that I should not conventions. 
So my question, is conventionMapping still the correct way to write a plugin which uses extension? If yes, what's the correct way of retrieving them without the gradle dsl magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convention mapping is the most powerful solution that's currently available to solve the "deferred configuration" problem, but it is considered an internal feature. At some point, it will go away in favor of the new configuration model (which will be a public feature). Meanwhile, another solution to solve the "deferred configuration" problem is to use callbacks such as `project.afterEvaluate { ... }`.

Comment: My custom plugin code looks very clean with afterEvaluate solution. Thanks Peter.

Comment: Just to be clear, can I take it that we should try __not__ to use conventionMapping as they might be removed in the future? Also, where can I get details about this new configuration model, are they available in Gradle 2.0?

Comment: When using internal features, the usual "use at your own risk" applies. Convention mapping will *definitely* go away, so as long as you can do without it, don't use it. The new configuration model is one of the main themes of 2.x. It's not available in 2.0.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Is there a plan for any replacement of `conventionMapping`? Deferring something into `afterEvaluate { }` makes pushing there dependent things necessary as well. Let say my custom plugin adds task of type `Zip` and sets `baseName` of it in `afterEvaluate` with value taken from the plugn's extension. Then a client project which utilizes this plugin and refers to the task like `myZipTask.archivePath` will get incorrect path unless `archivePath` call is done in `afterEvaluate` as well. It's not up to the client to guess such things upfront though, is it? Any tips about that?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Can you give an example how to do it using the 'afterEvaluate{}